# What are the problems of the MVVM pattern?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

Is Model-View-ViewModel the best pattern to use in WPF? Are there any downsides?

Comment: It was constructive!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's a good, short blog post on the [advantages and disadvantages of MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/johngossman/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-m-v-vm), straight from John Gossman (*) himself.

His main disadvantages are:

"For simple UI, M-V-VM can be overkill.  In bigger cases, it can be hard to design the ViewModel up front in order to get the right amount of generality.  Data-binding for all its wonders is declarative and harder to debug than nice imperative stuff where you just set breakpoints"

---

> John Gossman's blog was the original source of the pattern and he was the architect in charge of the team that "invented" it as a pattern.

Comment: who is John Gossman?

Comment: @shriduttkothari His blog was the original source of the pattern - he was the architect in charge of the team that "invented" it as a pattern :)

Comment: Wow great to know, this. Than I believe this info should be explicitly mentioned in your answer rather than just the name for people who don't know this. As people might not read these comments. Cheers !!

Answer (score 8):

To build our application, we started with MVVM, but after having much of problems we gave up on MVVM because of following reasons which will identify where not to use MVVM.

**Inheritance Problem**

We program in .NET, and we use C# and best we sure want Inheritance. C# does not support multiple class inheritance, so we can not have abstract classes with logic that will partially be reused in UI as well as logic.

Most of the time we are confused, how to design View Models so that we can inherit and control the logic.

If we inherit View, we can not inherit ViewModel same time, and if we inherit ViewModel then we can not inherit View at the same time. Instead we have to use very complicated generics and with help of tools like Prism and Unity we can achieve, but it is not worth the time.

**ViewModel to ViewModel Binding**

Well most of time business logic isnt that simple like A=B+C, UI and Response on UI plays a huge part. However we can bind UI's visual properties to View Model's data properties, but question comes on how to actually bind one view model to another view model, and if they go through two bindings of shared controls, then we have no idea of what will be executed first.

**ViewModel is not simple replacement of CodeBehind**

It is assumed that ViewModel is simple replacement of CodeBehind files. But while making our app, restriction on inheritance taught us that as it is WPF/Silverlight supports UI Style that can completely separate UI with logic, we are just over separating business logic in ViewModel.

**Repeated Code in ViewModel**

We eventually realized that we are just writing same pattern of code in every View and every ViewModel, changing which becomes a huge pain, and maintaining is a pain too. MVVM is more suitable for test driven development but when it comes to writing extensible components, they are not the best candidate.

---

WPF/Silverlight already lets you separate code and UI very nicely, we indeed now have designed very simple class hierarchy that performs business logic and give us all that we need. We now create all ICommand based command properties as dependency properties of our classes, that we bind within UserControl as well as Templated Control.

ICommand in CodeBehind or Template and Styles in ResourceDictionary gives us almost all benefits of what we can get over MVVM.

Comment: It's been a while since I asked the original question. In that time I've been using MVVM a lot in my project at work. So, with inheritance, you want a class that inherits from View and ViewModel at the same time? Is this class a View or a ViewModel? Repeated code in the ViewModels can be solved by using services and any sort of IOC. ViewModel binding and "ViewModel is not just CodeBehind" I agree with.

Comment: Service & IOC are very complex for midsize application. Worst part is, they are too difficult to debug and manage in small team. Though it has advantages, but for young blood it is way too complex.

Answer (score 7):

It is a great pattern and frankly one of the few flushed UI out patterns for WPF. What I mean by that is that many people understand and have adopted it. Therefore it's relatively easy to get help and information on it.

The biggest downside in my opinion is that it increases the number of classes and components in your application, because [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) trumps [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY) in this pattern. That being said, I think it is worth it.

Comment: > " SRP America’s back moles DRY in this patter" wtf does that mean? I tried reading it three times.

Comment: What I meant was this pattern favors having duplication of properties across similar looking objects in different layers (a potential DRY violation in 2009 thinking which is when I answered this question). It does this so that any changes to these objects are isolated just to the layers that need that change. This question was answered back in the days were it was common for people to bind their domain models directly to the UI and inevitably there would be conflicts between what the UI needed vs what the backend logic needed which is a SRP smell.

Comment: @oligofren - After re-reading your comment, I am wondering if you have a browser plugin running that turns the name of a certain former American President into gibberish.

Comment: haha, you are right! that was an awkward reveal. I just read your comment on another browser and it made total sense. I had forgotten all about installing this plugin years ago https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trump-be-gone/hdogoomobiommmfeekbmnmcogakplogm

Comment: Just wanted to note that MVVP also has a recent resurgence in the SPA/frontend world, allowing one to test all of the rendering logic of React/Angular/Vue/what-have-you apps without a single reference to any React libraries. A revelation :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's an overkill for small hello world-style applications.

Comment: which don't really exist

Answer (score 1):

Different patterns have different strengths. People tend to confuse the pattern with the implementation. How the business logic is arranged or accessed has an influence on which pattern is more natural for a give application. So whilst this question asks about WPF it may be helpful to read about three patterns used to impliment the same screen three times in any framework.

Below is a link to a java article which compares MVVM ("presentation model") with MVP ("passive view") and a hybrid implementation MVVMP/MVC ("supervising controller"). I believe that this is relevant to this question as it has a section which has a comparison of the patterns.

[Implementing event-driven GUI patterns using the ZK Java AJAX framework](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/zones/portal/proddoc/zkjavaajax/)

It points out the weakness which John Gossman makes but also goes on compare both strenghts and weaknesses with two alternative patterns.